# MySQL - can't get the result of non-matching records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get the result of a record which has a missing entry in the other table. I already tried using NOT IN and NOT EXIST but I cannot get the desired result. The output should be Kevin and US Visa since "Kevin" has no US Visa on the table tbl_personnel_documents but I always get an empty row. It should be like this:

```
name  | documentName  |  
----------------------
Kevin   US Visa
```

Note: I am trying to get the result by using only the vessel_id and lastJoinedVsl which in this case is id number 4.

Here's my code and sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46790e/1

Please help. Many Thanks

Comment: Don't use `LEFT` when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what your looking for is this:

I used this to find the abandoned the abandoned records:

```
SELECT tpd.id, tpi.name, td.id, td.documentName
FROM tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_info AS tpi ON tpi.id = tpd.personnel_id
RIGHT JOIN tbl_documents AS td ON td.id = tpd.document_id
;
```

Returns

```
TPD_ID, TPI_NAME, TD_ID,     TD_DOCNAME
-------------------------------------------
   '1',  'Kevin',   '1',    'PASSPORT'
   '2',  'Kevin',   '2',    'AUSTRALIAN VISA'
  NULL,     NULL,   '3',    'US VISA'
```

The reason you will not get the result

```
name  | documentName  |  
----------------------
Kevin   US Visa
```

Is because there is no value linking them.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

😁

EDIT 1:

If you want to filter them out you can use an `INNER JOIN` on your joins.

That will strip out all values that don't have a linking value, based on the query in your SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT tpd.id, tpi.name, td.id, td.documentName
FROM tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd
INNER JOIN tbl_personnel_info AS tpi ON tpi.id = tpd.personnel_id
INNER JOIN tbl_documents AS td ON td.id = tpd.document_id
;
```

If you want to see only the missing records you can use:

```
SELECT tpd.id, tpi.name, td.id, td.documentName
FROM tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_info AS tpi ON tpi.id = tpd.personnel_id
RIGHT JOIN tbl_documents AS td ON td.id = tpd.document_id
WHERE tpd.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, so does it mean that I won't be able to filter out to get the missing value? There's no other way?

Comment: FYI - if I added an edit to showcase this for you.